# How can I add the next even number to the current odd number and put it into a new array? This is what I've got so far

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment for computer science and I had to show the array that the user input, show the smallest even number which I have done, but now I have to add to every odd number to the even number that follows it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class P01ArrayIntsInit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
    System.out.println("Introduza 10 números inteiros: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numerosIntroduzidos = new int[10];
    int npar = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    int par = -1;
    int numeroIntroduzido;
    int temp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while ( indice < 10 ) {
        
        numeroIntroduzido = scan.nextInt(); 
        numerosIntroduzidos[indice] = numeroIntroduzido;
        //Get menor par
        if(numeroIntroduzido % 2 == 0) {
            npar = numeroIntroduzido;
            if(npar < temp) {
                temp = npar;
                par = temp;
            }
            
        }//Ends get menor par
        
        indice++;
    }//Ends while
    
    //Print menor par
    if(par != -1) {
        System.out.println("O menor número Par é: " + par);
        
    }//Ends print menor par
    
    //Print do array introduzido
    System.out.println("Array Introduzido --> " + Arrays.toString(numerosIntroduzidos));
    
    }//Ends main
    
}//Ends class
```

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: Please make sure that your actual problem and question are in the **body** of your question, not just in the title.

Comment: i need to add to every odd number the even number that follows it and print out the modified array like so, original[[8, 31, 20, 21, 67, 6, 35, 89, 309, 1], modified [8, 51, 20, 27, 73, 6, 35, 89, 309, 1]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this

```java
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class P01ArrayIntsInit {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Introduza 10 números inteiros: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numerosIntroduzidos = new int[10];
    int[] newArray = new int[20];
    int npar = 0;
    int nimpar = 0;
    int indice = 0;
    int indiceNewArray = 0;
    int par = -1;
    int numeroIntroduzido;
    int temp = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while (indice < 10) {

      numeroIntroduzido = scan.nextInt();
      numerosIntroduzidos[indice] = numeroIntroduzido;
      // Get menor par
      if (numeroIntroduzido % 2 == 0) {
        npar = numeroIntroduzido;
        if (npar < temp) {
          temp = npar;
          par = temp;
        }

      } // Ends get menor par

      newArray[indiceNewArray] = numeroIntroduzido;
      if (numeroIntroduzido % 2 != 0) {
        newArray[++indiceNewArray] = numeroIntroduzido + 1;
      } // Insert even number
      indice++;
      indiceNewArray++;
    } // Ends while

    // Print menor par
    if (par != -1) {
      System.out.println("O menor número Par é: " + par);

    } // Ends print menor par

    // Print do array introduzido
    System.out.println("Array Introduzido --> " + Arrays.toString(numerosIntroduzidos));
    System.out.println("Array new --> " + Arrays.toString(newArray));

  }//Ends main
        
    }//Ends class
```